# How do I write a serialized object into a resource file

Tags: java, file, serialization, inputstream, outputstream

So I'm trying to serialize data to make a game by saving objects. I've localized where the data gets written and read from the stream into a single class which has two simple methods that read an object out of a file, and to write an object out of a file. The main issue that I'm running into is that I just don't know how to get the file name to read or write, so whenever I try to call those methods, it just tells me that the system cannot find the path specified. This happens even though when I print out what the method finds, it results in the same file path that I can search for in my computer. I don't understand why the system can't find it.

```
public void SerializeObject(String file, Object obj) {

    URL o = getClass().getResource(file);
    String fileName = o.getPath();

    System.out.println(fileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        //fileOut.flush(); Does this clear current data in a file?
        out.writeObject(obj);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It will print the file path, and then tell me that it can't find it:

```
/C:/Users/Aiden/eclipse-workspace/Platformer%20Game/bin/savedata/options_data/resolution.ser
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Aiden\eclipse-workspace\Platformer%20Game\bin\savedata\options_data\resolution.ser (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I really don't understand why it can't find the file. I've also patchworked together this code, so if I wouldn't know if there's an issue with the way I'm approaching the issue in general.

How can I change the code so that the system recognizes the file path?

Comment: Try directly sending the file system path instead of getClass().getResource(file);

Comment: Two things: (1) Resources cannot be accessed the same way as files; (2) Resources should be considered read-only.

Comment: You don't. Resources are  not files. Rethink.